# Photoeletric Effect with Flames

Tags: energy, atomic-physics, photoelectric-effect

Can flames (fire) induce photoeletric effect? I mean, as I know, fire is electrons changing orbital levels, which implies a $\Delta E=hf$ that is a  photon being ejected. As it reaches the metal, and supposing velocity $v$ of the emitted electron is sufficient to take it out permanently, we have that $\Delta E > \phi_m +E_c$ and by some time we would have a positive charged metal. Is this correct?

Comment: Photons of the same wavelength are indistinguishable from one another. The effect that photons of some given wavelength have on a metal target is the same no matter how the photons were created.

Comment: @SolomonSlow sorry for the ambiguous post, I already changed it. It is the electron velocity.

Comment: It is called [thermionic emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_emission).

Comment: @Farcher thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do the experiment. Understand that digital cameras work via the photoelectric effect: photons liberate electrons within silicon, and the circuitry collects those electrons to sense the image.

Point a digital camera at a flame, and take a picture. Does the flame appear in the image? If yes, photons from the flame are producing the photoelectric effect in the camera.